# execute jquery function when data-ajax=“true”

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile app developed using jquery mobile. One one page i have a chart. When the user clicks on `<a href="chart.html" data-ajax=“true”>Chart</a>` the page loads but the chart doesnt load. When i refresh the page the chart works.

When `data-ajax=“false”` the page works but its not smooth and doest have the transition effects

Below is my chart code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var limit = 10000;    //increase number of dataPoints by increasing the limit
    var y = 0;
    var data = [];
    var dataSeries = { type: "line" };
    var dataPoints = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < limit; i += 1) {
        y += (Math.random() * 10 - 5);
        dataPoints.push({
            x: i,
            y: y
        });
    }
    dataSeries.dataPoints = dataPoints;
    data.push(dataSeries);

    //Better to construct options first and then pass it as a parameter
    var options = {
        zoomEnabled: true,
                animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Try Zooming - Panning"
        },
        axisX: {
            labelAngle: 30
        },
        axisY: {
            includeZero: false
        },
        data: data  // random data
    };

    $("#chartContainer").CanvasJSChart(options);

});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

Is there away to execute the chart function without setting `data-ajax=“false”` ?

Comment: Run chart js code when chart.html page is loaded and visible. Listen to `pagecontainershow` event.

Comment: @Omar even the page is fully loaded the chart doesnt  work unless i refresh. Also how can i use `pagecontainershow ` ?

Comment: https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/ how to use pagecontainer events.

Answer (score 0):

To work with complicated charts, i usually use [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo), it is very responsive and very customizable, and it also have very smooth transition effect when it shows.
Here is a [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/) on JSFiddle.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    type: 'column'
},
title: {
    text: 'Column chart with negative values'
},
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
},
credits: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
}, {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
}, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
}]
```

});

I hope it help.

Comment: the problem is not the chart.. It doesnt load when `data-ajax` is true